# How to click on Text link in frame pop up using selenium python?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am learning selenium for web scraping.I want to click on a link using selenium But could not find a way to do that.The problem is the link opens in a new frame inside a webpage and i can't locate any element on that frame.

I have attached a picture of that pop up frame and source code of that frame.I hope there is a way to solve this issue.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

[image]

the code i have tried :

```
try:

browser.get('link')

browser.switch_to.frame(0)

myElem_1 = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Manually enter account & routing info')))
myElem_1.click()
except:
      pass
```

Comment: you dont show the inspector code of popup corresponding to your picture

Comment: first one is frame view source code ad second one is inspect code

Comment: could you show the code you have tried?

Comment: browser.get('url')                                                                                                                                 browser.switch_to.frame(0)

Comment: i suggest you to show your complete code if you want some help its more a code problem.. and add tag of corresponding code

Comment: check update . I simple open url that contains the iframe then switch to iframe and try to find the  text link .@Frenchy

Comment: i cant test, i have no iframe when i launch your url, i just arrives on login/password

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238858/discussion-between-zulqarnain-sabir-and-frenchy).

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have translated C# to your langage, not sure about By.Id but you will fix that.

just fyi its not alink but a button, you cant find it by linktext.

```
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('https://link.goes/here')
frame = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'wepay-ach')))

browser.switch_to.frame(frame);
but = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'microdeposit-button')))

but.Click();
```

Comment: ID is capital in python(By.ID) , by it is not clicking there

Comment: i have no problem, are you sure to use id for the iframe too?

Comment: another thing dont forget to maximize , you cant click on button not visible..

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you must:

1. first switch to the iframe … *driver.switch_to.frame(frame_reference)*
2. do your testing in the iframe
3. switch back in the main window … *driver.switch_to.default_content()*

Comment: I did the same .Switched to iframe ,but  i cant find elemnts in iframe .It seems that the script in iframe is doing hidden things